# paperjs - How to apply brightness/contrast like effects on the raster image?

Tags: paperjs

I have tried to apply the image adjustment options using `paper.js`, but it will only apply to the `fillcolor`.

Does anyone know how to apply *brightness*, *contrast* or *other* image adjustments to the raster image?

For example:

```
var url = 'http://images.com/q.jpg';
var raster = new paper.Raster(url);
raster.brightness = .5;
```

Are there any pre-defined functions available for image adjustment in `paper.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, but you can play with [blend modes](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#blendmode) or [opacity](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#opacity).

I would advise using specialized WebGL libraries like [glfx](https://github.com/evanw/glfx.js) or [webgl-filter](http://evanw.github.io/webgl-filter/) for image effects (I didn't try them, but they seem powerful).

Answer (score 0):

```
function reDrawImage(lightness = 10,contrast = 1.5) {
  const raster = paper.project.activeLayer.children[0] as paper.Raster
  const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = currentRaster.getContext(true)
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, currentRaster.width, currentRaster.height)
  for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imageData.data[i] = saturate_cast(imageData.data[i] * (contrast + lightness));
    imageData.data[i+1] = saturate_cast(imageData.data[i+1] * (contrast + lightness));
    imageData.data[i+2] = saturate_cast(imageData.data[i+2] * (contrast + lightness));
  }
  raster.setImageData(imageData, new Point(0, 0))
}


function saturate_cast(num: number) {
  if (num > 255) {
    return 255
  }

  if (num < 0) {
    return 0
  }

  return num
}
```